# python plot one bar with different color by time

Tags: python, plot, colors

Here's the dataset. How can plot it in one bar with different colors based on time?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'Time (s)': ['30', '1:30', '1:45', '2:10','2:30'],
        'Color': ['red','grey','purple','green','NAN']})


Time (s)    Color
0   30  red
1   1:30    grey
2   1:45    purple
3   2:10    green
4   2:30    NAN
```

An example is below. The x axis label can be with same interval. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Based on the answer from below, the final solution is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({'Time (s)': ['0:30', '1:30', '1:45', '2:10','2:30'],
        'Color': ['red','grey','purple','green','NAN']})
data['Duration'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time (s)'], format='%M:%S') ## Column as datetime

fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,1))

## Iterate and draw each barh
for i in range(len(data)-1):
    ax.broken_barh([(data.Duration[i], data.Duration[i+1] - data.Duration[i])], yrange = (1, 0.5), facecolor = data.Color[i]) 

## Adjust to show only the xticks and xticklabels with the entries in the dataframe
ax.set_xticks(data['Duration'].to_list())
ax.set_xticklabels(data['Time (s)'].to_list())
ax.set_yticks([])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matplotlib's `broken_barh()` to do this... one of the many ways. Below code will do this. Note that your first element (30) is incorrect, it should be in HH:MM format, so I changed it to `0:30`.

First create a datetime equivalent for each of the time format, which will help you measure the x-length for each of the entries. The facecolor of the barh can be set to the Color column, so that the right color is provided for each bar. For each row in the dataframe, you can create a separate rectangle bar. Finally use `set_xticks()` and `set_xticklabels()` to set the labels to the start and end times correctly. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'Time (s)': ['0:30', '1:30', '1:45', '2:10','2:30'],
        'Color': ['red','grey','purple','green','NAN']})
data['Duration'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time (s)'], format='%H:%M') ## Column as datetime

fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,1))

## Iterate and draw each barh
for i in range(len(data)-1):
    ax.broken_barh([(data.Duration[i], data.Duration[i+1] - data.Duration[i])], yrange = (1, 0.5), facecolor = data.Color[i]) 

## Adjust to show only the xticks and xticklabels with the entries in the dataframe
ax.set_xticks(data['Duration'].to_list())
ax.set_xticklabels(data['Time (s)'].to_list())
ax.set_yticks([])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. The only thing is time unit. It's second, so the format should be '%M:%S'. I post the final solution in the question.